# Why do I get these this error in this bash script?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash ping sweeper and I get two error messages.

The first is:

```
./pingsweep.sh: line 2: [192.168.199.182: command not found
```

The second is

```
ping: 192.168.199.182.seq: Name or service not known.
```

I cant spot the error from the initial code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ["$1" == ""]
then
    echo "Usages:./pingsweep.sh [network]"
    echo "Example: ./pingsweep.sh 192.168.199"
else
    for ip in 'seq 1 254'; do
        ping -c 1 $1.$ip | grep "64 bytes" | cut -d " " -f 4 | sed 's/.$//'&
    done
fi
```

Comment: You need a space after `[` and before `]` in your `if` statement. Otherwise, `bash` sees `["$1"` as a single string/command. It will also see `""]` as a single string.

Comment: pasting your code to https://shellckeck.net will help you find many syntax errors like that. Good luck.

Comment: You also need to use back ticks (\`) instead of single quotes in your `seq` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your segment `["$1"` constructs a *single* word starting with `[` and ending with whatever you passed as the first argument. Because that's not one of the bash builtins (like `[`), it tries to run it as a command and fails:

```
./pingsweep.sh: line 2: [192.168.199.182: command not found
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                        |
                        +--> see *especially* this first character.
```

You need a space between `[` and the variable, and before the closing `]` as well. Even if this *weren't* necessary for syntax, it would be required for my OCD sensibilities :-)

```
if [ "$1" == "" ]
```

Additionally, the command `for ip in 'seq 1 254'` (note the single quotes) will iterate over the *one* string `seq 1 254`, *not* run the command and iterate over its output. For that, you need to use backticks (`` ` ``) rather than quotes, or my preference since they're easier to nest:

```
for ip in $(seq 1 254)
```

But you should keep in mind that `bash` actually has decent loops *without* having to resort to `seq`:

```
for (( ip=1; ip<10; ip++ )); do echo $ip; done
```

Comment: thanks i now get this bash commands with your help and the for (( ip=1; ip<10; ip++ )); do echo $ip; done really solved it.Thanks ones again